# How is useState() updating my data here? STRANGE

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I have data from an movie-api I want to sort based on a select menu, either by year in descending order or title in alphabetical order.

Although Im only updating state in the sort function, not using the variable any where, the data thats already mapped out, and in a different array, updates accordingly. I guess its somehow related to the first change in state for each of the two differen variables?

Any idea how I should solve this correctly and why this is happening?

```
 const sortData = (e) => {
    if (e === "year"){

      const yearData = data.sort(function(a, b) {
        const yearA = a.Year;
        const yearB = b.Year;
        if (yearA < yearB) {
          return -1;
        }
        if (yearA > yearB) {
          return 1;
        }
        return 0;
      });
      setYearData(yearData);
      }
    if (e === "title") {
    
      const titleData = data.sort(function(a, b) {
        const titleA = a.Title.toUpperCase();
        const titleB = b.Title.toUpperCase();
        if (titleA < titleB) {
          return -1;
        }
        if (titleA > titleB) {
          return 1;
        }
        return 0;
      });
      setTitleData(titleData);
      

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sort() method sorts the elements of an array **in place**, so the data(state) changed without using setState (It may cause some unpredictability happened in the execution)

You can use the sort() method on a copy of the array, so it doesn't affect your state array, I guess this change may work:

use `[...data].sort(...)` instead of `data.sort(...)`

Comment: Spreading data and using the sorted array to update the state to data did the trick. Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

`Array.sort()`, in your case `data.sort()` *updates* the original array in addition to returning it. Seems like your `data` variable is some sort of global that gets changed during `sort()`.

Comment: Im using a different useState to controll the variable data